# How to dynamically add ResourceDictionary to MergedDictionaries in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, resourcedictionary, win-universal-app

I have the next WPF part of code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Languages/English.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Languages/Romana.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

How can I select from code one of those ResourceDictionarys?

EDIT:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Languages/English.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Languages/Romana.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  BorderThickness="0,3,0,3" BorderBrush="Aqua">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <AppBarToggleButton x:Name="Connect_toggle" Label="{StaticResource connect}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Icon="Accept" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Click="Connect_toggle_Click"/>
            <AppBarToggleButton x:Name="Options_toggle" Label="{StaticResource options}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Icon="Accept" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Click="Options_toggle_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I did not specify that I am using Windows Universal (VS2015).

Comment: What do you mean by 'select code'?  They're all merged together - you can select individual resources by key, if that's what you mean?

Comment: I want to use just one of those. For example: i have a comboBox and if i select "English", my application will load English.xaml. Select Romana will load Romana.xaml. Actually, those xaml files define my application language

Comment: @CharlesMager, *select from code* or as we usually say *in code behind*, so the question is [how to merge ResourceDictionary in code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2622447/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr: it seems OP is actually asking how to dynamically switch between various ResourceDictionary. Best regards,

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically select the `ResourceDictionary` file and add it to `MergedDictionaries` using C# code-behind like shown in the following code snippet:

```
    // prefix to the relative Uri for resource (xaml file)
    string _prefix = String.Concat(typeof(App).Namespace, ";component/");

    // clear all ResourceDictionaries
    this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

    // add ResourceDictionary
    this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add
    (
        new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(String.Concat(_prefix + "Languages/English.xaml", UriKind.Relative) }
    );
```

where "`Languages/English.xaml`" is a sample relative path to selected `ResourceDictionary` file pertinent to your example.

Hope this may help.

Comment: It doesn't work. In debug mode, it returns me this error: An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in Internal.Uri.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: See the extended answer. Best regards,

Comment: Please post the entire code block pertinent to the case and highlight the line causing the error. Regards,

Comment: EDITED! Check it now, please

Comment: Where is C# code pertinent to that ComboBox event handler (quote: "For example: i have a comboBox and if i select "English",...") and what is the line in that code block causing the error?  Regards,

Comment: I didn't create that comboBox yet. Was just an example. Instead a combobox, can be a button. The idea is that i want to change all my labels from my application when i select a language

Comment: new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(String.Concat(_prefix + "Languages/English.xaml", UriKind.Relative)) } This line is causing my error

Comment: Where did you put that line if you don't have a ComboBox control and therefore, no any event handlers associated with that control?

Comment: In a typical WPF app you should have MainWindow.xaml and a code behind MainWindow.xaml.cs. Place your control and event handler w/code snippet in that Window and it will work. Regards,